# Access childAutoID to update selected child value in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In order to populate my tableView, I append items (created from a struct) to a local array:

```
func loadList() {
        var newAnnotations: [AnnotationListItem] = []
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in

            for item in snapshot.children {
                let annotationItem = AnnotationListItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
                newAnnotations.append(annotationItem)
            }
            annotationList = newAnnotations
            self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .fade)
        })
    }
}
```

When I click a specific row, I am taken to a `DetailViewController` where it is only a large `UITextView` (named notes). The `UITextView.text` displayed is based on the selected `indexPath.row` and the "notes" value is retrieved from the array. Now the user is able to type some text and when they are done, the `textViewDidEndEditing` function is called:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    notes.resignFirstResponder()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

    let newNotes = self.notes.text
    print(newNotes!)
}
```

Now I'd like to `updateChildValues` to `newNotes` to the child node "notes" in my JSON:

```
"users" : {
  "gI5dKGOX7NZ5UBqeTdtu30Ze9wG3" : {
    "annotations" : {
      "-KuWIRBARv7osWr3XDZz" : {
        "annotationSubtitle" : "1 Cupertino CA",
        "annotationTitle" : "Apple Infinite Loop",
        "notes" : "Does it work?!",
    }
```

How can I access the selected `autoID` so I can update the specific `notes` node. So far the best I have is:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").(somehow access the specific childID).updateChildValues(["notes": newNotes])
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

The `annotationListItem` struct is created:

```
struct AnnotationListItem {

let key: String?
var annotationTitle: String?
let annotationSubtitle: String?
let notes: String?
let ref: DatabaseReference?

init(key: String = "", annotationTitle: String, annotationSubtitle: String, notes: String) {
    self.key = key
    self.annotationTitle = annotationTitle
    self.annotationSubtitle = annotationSubtitle
    self.notes = notes
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    annotationTitle = snapshotValue["annotationTitle"] as? String
    annotationSubtitle = snapshotValue["annotationSubtitle"] as? String
    notes = snapshotValue["notes"] as? String
    ref = snapshot.ref
}

init(Dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.key = Dictionary["key"] as? String
    self.annotationTitle = Dictionary["annotationTitle"] as? String
    self.annotationSubtitle = Dictionary["annotationSubtitle"] as? String
    self.notes = Dictionary["notes"] as? String
    self.ref = nil
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "annotationTitle": annotationTitle as Any,
        "annotationSubtitle": annotationSubtitle as Any,
        "notes": notes as Any
    ]
}
}
```

***UPDATE***

This is how the `annotationListItem` is created to be stored in Firebase:

```
// Using the current user’s data, create a new AnnotationListItem that is not completed by default
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
    let title = placemark.name
    let subtitle = annotation.subtitle
    let notes = ""

    // declare variables
    let annotationListItem = AnnotationListItem(
        annotationTitle: title!,
        annotationSubtitle: subtitle!,
        notes: notes)

    // Add the annotation under their UID
    let userAnnotationItemRef = uidRef.child(uid!).child("annotations").childByAutoId()
    userAnnotationItemRef.setValue(annotationListItem.toAnyObject())
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for `AnnotationListItem` ?

Comment: You mean how its created or the specific struct?

Comment: The specific struct code please

Comment: Updated. There may be some unnecessary things in there but I'm new to Swift and its a large combination of different things I've looked up

Comment: As I can see you are storing the value of autoChildId as `key` in your struct, right? so I think you can use this to update the childvalues in the database, please check if you understand and please ask if you face problem

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I've added another update to show you how the `annotationListItem` is created. As far as I'm aware, the key value isn't even being used?

Comment: Ok add these two print statements in your code to see this: first add `print(item.key)` inside `for` loop in `loadList` function and then add this `print(key)` after `key = snapshot.key` inside `init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)` method inside `AnnotationListItem` struct. These two statements will tell you that you have the `childAutoId` in your struct or not

Comment: In the load list when I tried to run the project, I have the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'key'" so I am assuming it's not there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154946/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-zachenn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need to do this:(since you have declared the note as global)

```
 guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return } 
uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").(note.key).updateChildValues(["notes": newNotes])
```

inside the method where you change the notes

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you are creating an array of a custom object?

```
var newAnnotations: [AnnotationListItem] = []
```

You could do something like: `var newAnnotations: [(key: String, value: [String : Any])] = []` (`Any` only if you are going to have `Strings`, `Integers`, ect. If it'll only be `String` then specify it as a `String`.

Accessing the key would be: `newAnnotations[indexPath.row].key` in your `cellForRowAtIndex` of your `tableView`. Accessing values would be: `newAnnotations[indexPath.row].value["NAME"]`.

You can have a separate array that holds the key and just append it at the same time as your population:

```
for item in snapshot.children {
      guard let itemSnapshot = task as? FDataSnapshot else {
           continue
      }
      let id = task.key //This is the ID
      let annotationItem = AnnotationListItem(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
      newAnnotations.append(annotationItem)
}
```

Another thing you could do is go up one more level in your firebase call:

```
if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        uidRef.child(uid).child("annotations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            if snapshot is NSNull{
                //Handles error
            } else{
                if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{ //(or [String: String]
                    //set localDictionary equal to value
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .fade)
        })
    }
```

And then when you select a row: let selectedItem = `localDictionary.allKeys[indexPath.row] as! String` //This is the ID you pass to your viewController.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will study it to understand what you've shared with me. I've had a lengthy discussion with 3stud1ant3 and we have discovered an alternate solution, so I will have to accept his answer. Thank you anyways

Comment: No worries! Glad your received an answer!